# Google Timeline fix different color for each timesheets

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I have a timeline with a lot of rows and in each rows are several timesheets.

I would like to fix for each timesheet an exact color, so one type of timesheet will have same color in every row.

I am using this code:

```
var options = {
      colors: ['#0C14F2', '#114C9E', '#ee8800', '#F6FF00'],
      timeline: {
          showBarLabels: false,
          avoidOverlappingGridLines: false
      },
      backgroundColor: '#f8f8ff'    
  };
```

This code changes the colors seemly randomly of timesheets.

**UPDATE: Sample JSON output**

```
{"cols":[{"label":"Name","type":"string"},{"label":"Description","type":"string"},{"label":"Start","type":"date"},{"label":"End","type":"date"},{"role":"style","type":"string"}],"rows":
[{"c":[{"v":"Sample Name"},{"v":"Sample Desc"},{"v":"Date(2014,09,09,0,0,0)"},{"v":"Date(2014,09,09,1,0,0)"},{"v":"#124T‌​9E"}]},
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the "colors" option is not the best approach, as the process for setting this option correctly to get the colors you want is rather complex.  A much simpler way to do this is to use a "style" role column that has the desired color for the bar listed directly in it, eg:

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Category', 'Name', {role: 'style'}, 'Start', 'End'],
    ['Foo', 'Cad', '#a23c7a', new Date(2014, 7, 1), new Date(2014, 7, 5)],
    ['Foo', 'Qud', '#40a67d', new Date(2014, 7, 3), new Date(2014, 7, 4)],
    ['Bar', 'Fiz', '#5581b4', new Date(2014, 7, 2), new Date(2014, 7, 9)]
]);
```

see example: http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/qgo310pc/1/

**[Edit in response to comments]**

You can create the column in PHP like this:

```
$table = array(
    'cols' => array(
        array('label' => 'Name', 'type' => 'string'),
        array('label' => 'Description', 'type' => 'string'),
        array('role' => 'style', 'type' => 'string'),
        array('label' => 'Start', 'type' => 'date'),
        array('label' => 'End', 'type' => 'date')
    )
);
```

Comment: It seems great, but how can I implement it in a PHP array? Like this: 
http://paste.ubuntu.com/8256849/

Comment: Can I store color codes in simple variables, like this?
$color='#ef8602';

Comment: Yes you can store the colors in variables, just use the variable in the data array in place of the color string.

Comment: I store now this so:
{"role":"style","type":"string"}
{"v":"#114C9E"}
But it uses Google's default colors instead of my colors.

Comment: If I use fields in another order: "Invalid data table format: column #2 must be of type 'date,number,datetime'."

Comment: Update your question with the PHP code that generates your DataTable and a sample of what the output from `$table` is.

Comment: 1 row: [{"c":[{"v":"Sample Name"},{"v":"Sample Desc"},{"v":"Date(2014,09,09,0,0,0)"},{"v":"Date(2014,09,09,1,0,0)"},{"v":"#124T9E"}]},

Comment: The color needs to be the 3rd column (per the `$table['cols']` array in my answer), not the last.

Comment: Yes, I see, but if it is the 3rd I get this error: "Invalid data table format: column #2 must be of type 'date,number,datetime'." It is true, because I store color code as string.

Comment: Update your question with a sample of the output from `$table`.

Comment: I have added some output.

Comment: If you put the style column 3rd (and fix the color value, as `'#124T‌​9E'` from your output is not a valid color string), it should work: http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/z4p9tsh4/

Comment: Okay, I fixed these to valid color codes, but if I use this my JSON output is only this:
{"cols":[{"label":"Name","type":"string"},{"label":"Description","type":"string"},{"role":"style","type":"string"},{"label":"Start","type":"date"},{"label":"End","type":"date"}]}
and this is the message on the frontend: "Invalid data table format: column #2 must be of type 'date,number,datetime'."

Comment: Do you have a public-facing page I can test this on?

Comment: I use a local database, so sorry, but I have no public page. I can share only the output above. I only can not imagine, what causes the error above, if I use color as 3rd...

Comment: The output you posted is missing the "rows" attribute.  Is this the actual output from your PHP, or did you omit the data?  If you omitted the data, can you post the complete JSON output so I can test it?

Comment: Here is a working test: http://jsfiddle.net/kovacsdev/xvgnwpjw/1/
So, I am using code of a green color. You can test it also for more description per row, but unfortunately it is not working properly.

Comment: If you put the style column 3rd (and place the color string values 3rd in each row to match), it works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/xvgnwpjw/2/